# Issue with assembly MASM32 procedure parameters ( missing operator in expression )

Tags: assembly, x86, irvine32, masm32

I want a procedure named aprint that takes 2 parameters. One is an array address and the other is a number of cells in the array. I especially had an issue trying to define the address of an array as a parameter but now that I've reached my current setup, I still receive errors.

My prototype is:

```
Aprint proto Arrayn:ptr byte, Asz:dword
```

The procedure is called using:

```
invoke APrint ArrayX, number
```

(where I have defined ArrayX in my .data section as  ArrayX dword 12 dup (?) )

My compiler tells me I am invoking incorrectly but I am not sure how else to define the parameters...

Complete code :

```
     ; Program Description: Fill an array with 12 random numbers generated between -7 and 15. Then swap first cell with last cell 
; and so on. Print original and swapped array on seperate lines.
; ----------------------------------
 include c:\asmio\asm32.inc
 includelib c:\asmio\asm32.lib
 includelib c:\asmio\user32.lib
 includelib c:\asmio\kernel32.lib
 ; ------------------------------------------------------------

APrint proto Array:dword, Asz:dword

 .const
 NULL = 0
 SIX = 6
 ; -----------------------------------
 .data ; Data section

 ArrayX dword 12 dup (?) ; Uninitialized cells 
 MINV dword -7
 MAXV dword 15
 number dword 12
 emptyy byte "  ", NULL



 ; -------------------------------------------------------------
 .code 



 main proc
 call randomize

 ;Load the array with random numbers between (-7 & 15)-------------------------------------------------------- 
 mov ecx, number
 mov esi, OFFSET ArrayX

 RN1:
 mov eax, MAXV
 sub eax, MINV
 inc eax 
 call randomrange ; generates a # between 0 and (MAX-MIN+1)
 mov [esi], eax
 add esi, TYPE dword
 loop RN1 

;Print filled array and skip a line --------------------------------------------------------------------------
invoke APrint ArrayX, number
call CrLf 

;Use a loop to swap first cell with last cell, second cell with second to last and so on --------------------------

mov esi, OFFSET ArrayX ; points at first cell
mov edi, OFFSET ArrayX + SIZEOF ArrayX ; points at last cell
sub edi, TYPE ArrayX
mov ecx, SIX

switchh: mov ebx, esi 
         mov esi, edi
         mov edi, ebx
         add esi, TYPE DWORD
         sub edi, TYPE DWORD
LOOP switchh
; Print new swapped array
invoke APrint ArrayX, number


 ret 0 ; Must return 0 in ASM
 main endp ; Ends the main procedure



 APrint proc Array:dword, Asz:dword
        mov eax, [Array]
        mov ecx, Asz
        mov ebx, OFFSET emptyy
   L1:  
        call WriteInt
        add eax, TYPE dword
        call  WriteString 
        LOOP L1

        ret
        APrint endp

 end main ; Ends the whole program
 ; --------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do i correctly define the parameters for this procedure?

Error Log:

```
[15:11:29] Build started...
[15:11:29] Warning! Errors have occurred in the build:
 Assembling: C:\Users\yp0l0\AppData\Local\Temp\SASM\program.asm
C:\Users\yp0l0\AppData\Local\Temp\SASM\program.asm(48) : error A2206: missing operator in expression
C:\Users\yp0l0\AppData\Local\Temp\SASM\program.asm(65) : error A2206: missing operator in expression
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file "C:\Users\yp0l0\AppData\Local\Temp\SASM\program.o"
```

Comment: `Arrayn:ptr byte` should be `dword` of course.

Comment: @Jester Thanks for the reply. That make sense but when I try to implement it, I get the same errors. I have updated my complete code.

Comment: I would try `invoke APrint offset ArrayX, [number]`. But please post the actual error message and confirm it's referencing that line.

Comment: Thanks again @Jester I originally had tried using offset and had the same error. I've added the error log

Comment: The error messages don't seem to line up with the code you've shown us. Line 51 is a comment.

Comment: Also your `end main` should be at the end of the file, otherwise the whole  `APrint` procedure might be omitted. If you have a problem with `invoke` you should reduce the code by throwing out everything else to produce a [mcve].

Comment: There must be a comma after the procedure name. `invoke APrint, ArrayX, number`